# Python regex extracting digits from scientific papers

Tags: python, regex

I don't know if I'm posting this at the right place, but I hope I can get some help from someone.

I'm a psychologist and not very skilled in programming. Nonetheless, I am working on a tool which uses regular expressions to extract statistical values from PDFs.

An issue has come up which I am not able to solve myself.

I need to extract numbers from the following term:

```
'F(1,110) = 15.18'
```

I need one regular expression to extract the two numbers in the bracket and one regular expression to extract the number after the "=". 
NOTE: numbers in the bracket can change and are different for every string.

Can anybody help me out?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
r'(F(\d+.\d+))',
r'(F([:digit:], [:digit:]) = \d+.\d+)'
```

No values are detected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that Python `re` does not support POSIX character classes, no need trying `[:digit:]` or `[[:digit:]]`

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/ZHhzr9, `re.search(r'F\((\d+),(\d+)\)', s)` and `re.search(r'=\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', s)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/ - try this playground to design your regexes. Paste some text you want to use it on, paste your regex, edit regex until successful. ;) First thing I notice: if you need literal `(` and `)` characters, you need to escape them (`\(` and `\)`).

Comment: `r'F\((?P<args>\d+\,\d+)\) = (?P<value>\d+\.\d+)'` - if you use this, you can extract 1st number as `.group('args')` and second as `.group('value')` (`(?P...)` are named groups in Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use 3 capturing groups escaping the parenthesis to match them literally.

If you can also use a single pattern instead of 2 separate patterns:

```
F\((\d+),(\d+)\) = (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

- `F` Match literally
- `\(` Match `(`
- `(\d+),(\d+)` Capture 2 times 1+ digits in a group with a comma in between
- `\)` Match `)`
- `=`  Match an equals sign surrounded by 2 spaces
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture in a group matching 1+ digits with an optional part for decimals

If the last part should contains a decimal, you could use `(\d+\.\d+)`instead.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9AdkIa/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/b5jEz0)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"F\((\d+),(\d+)\) = (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
s = "F(1,110) = 15.18"
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Result

```
[('1', '110', '15.18')]
```

Comment: The thing is i want two separate patterns because  i need to categorize the data as a next step. (first two values are degrees of freedom and the third value is the f-value). Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @sascha91 If you want 2 patterns, you could keep the same pattern but divide the capturing groups over 2 patterns for example https://regex101.com/r/J9ESxV/1 and https://regex101.com/r/J9ESxV/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use [next](https://regex101.com/r/xRv14R/2) regex:

```
F\((\d+) ?, ?(\d+)\) ?= ?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Code:

```
import re

strings = ["F(1,110) = 15.18", "F(1,110) =15.18", "F(1,110)= 15.18", "F(1,110)=15.18", "F(1, 110)=15.18", "F(1 ,110)=15.18", "F(1 , 110)=15.18", "F(1,110) = 100"]
for string in strings:
    matches = re.search(r"F\((\d+) ?, ?(\d+)\) ?= ?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", string)
    print(f"\"{string}\" => {', '.join(matches.groups())}")\
```